# Help with Circular Linked List in Python

Tags: python, linked-list, circular-list

I'm trying to make a circular singly linked list. I'd like to be able to modify my code for a singly liked list but I'm have some trouble.

For my linked list I have:

```
class Link (object):
  def __init__ (self, data, next = None):
    self.data = data
    self.next = next


class LinkedList(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.first = None

  def __str__(self):
    a = "["
    current = self.first
    while current != None:
      a += str(current.data) + ', ' 
      current = current.next
    a = a[:-2] + ']'  
    return a  

  def __iter__(self):
    current = self.first
    a = []
    while current != None:
      a += [current.data]
      current = current.next
    return iter(a)

  def __len__ (self):
    current = self.first
    a = []
    while current != None:
      a += [current.data]
      current = current.next
    return len(a)

  def InsertFirst(self, item):
    NewLink = Link(item, self.first)
    self.first = NewLink

  def InsertLast(self, item):
    NewLink = Link(item)
    current = self.first

    if current == None:
      self.first = NewLink  
      return 

    while current.next != None:
      current = current.next
    current.next = NewLink 

  def Search(self, item):
    count = 0
    current = self.first
    while current != None:
      count += 1
      if current.data == item:
        return count
      else:
        pass
        current = current.next
    return -1

  def Delete(self, item):
    current = self.first
    previous = self.first

    if (current == None):
      return None

    while (current.data != item):
      if (current.next == None):
        return None
      else:
        previous = current
        current = current.next

    if (current == self.first):
      self.first = self.first.next
    else:
      previous.next = current.next

    return current
```

So far for my circular list I have:

```
class Link (object):
  def __init__ (self, data, next = None):
    self.data = data
    self.next = next


class CircularList(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.first = Link(None, None)
    self.head = Link(None, self.first)

  def __str__(self):
    a = "["
    current = self.first
    while current != None:
      a += str(current.data) + ', ' 
      current = current.next
    a = a[:-2] + ']'  
    return a  

  def InsertLast(self, item):
    NewLink = Link(item)
    current = self.first

    if current == None:
      self.first = NewLink  
      return 

    while current.next != None:
      current = current.next
    current.next = Link(item)
```

My question is how do I link the last element back to the first so I can transverse?

Comment: I haven't looked at it throughly but it would be something like last.next = first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The point of a circular linked list is to skip all of the "if next is not None" logic.  At the beginning, the head points to itself, indicating that the list is empty.  There is no need to create an empty "first" - at the very start do:

```
self.head = Link(None, None)
self.head.next = self.head
```

Then to insert a node after some other node, you just do:

```
def insert_after(insert_node, after_node):
    insert_node.next = after_node.next
    after_node.next = insert_node
```

To insert at the beginning of the list, do:

```
insert_after(node, head)
```

Insert before requires iterating to find the "before" node, since the list is only singly linked:

```
def insert_before(node, before_node):
    loc = head
    while loc.next is not before_node:
        loc = loc.next
    insert_after(insert_node, loc)
```

To insert at the end of the list, do:

```
insert_before(node, head)
```

To get all elements of the list do:

```
current = self.head.next
while current is not self.head:
    # do something with current.data

    # advance to next element
    current = current.next
```

But the real power in a circular list is to make it doubly linked, so you can insert before without iterating.

Comment: `while current != self.head` might be better as `while current is not self.head`, no?

Comment: Thank you, how prompt! I will be removing my comments :D

Answer (score 2):

last.next = first when created?

```
class Link (object):
  def __init__ (self, data, next = None):
    self.data = data
    self.next = self.first
```

Might not be valid code. But since you're guaranteed to be at the last part of the list when creating then you might as well.

Comment: Beat me to it by 5 seconds; damn you! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class cirlist(list):
    def __init__(self,*arg):
        super(cirlist,self).__init__(*arg)
        self.m=super(cirlist,self).__getitem__(0)
        self.Index=0
    def next(self):
        if self.Index>=super(cirlist,self).__len__()-1:
            self.m=super(cirlist,self).__getitem__(0)
        else:
            self.m=super(cirlist,self).__getitem__(self.Index+1)
        if self.Index>super(cirlist,self).__len__()-1:    
            self.Index=super(cirlist,self).index(self.m)+1
        else:
            self.Index=super(cirlist,self).index(self.m)
        return self.m
```

Comment: next attribute will give the next element from the list everytime.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Link (object):

def __init__(self, first=None, rest=None):
    self.first = first
    self.rest = rest
def get_data(self):
    return self.first
def get_next(self):
    return self.rest
def __getitem__(self, i):
    if i ==  0:
        return self.first
    get = self
    while i > 0:
        get = get.rest
        i -= 1
    if get == None:
        raise IndexError('The Sentence Index is Out of Range.')
    return get.first
```

class Circular_Link (object):

```
def __init__(self, things):
    assert len(things) > 2
    last = Link(things[len(things)-1])
    first = Link(things[len(things)-2], last)
    index = len(things)-2
    while index > 0:
        index -= 1
        first = Link(things[index], first)
    last.rest = first
    self.circle = first
def __getitem__(self, i):
    return self.circle[i]
```

This example initializes the circular list from a normal list.

Answer (score -1):

The class Node will create an empty node and the insert function will create a node by calling Node class. Then we check for the head node and in case empty , create the new node as head node.else search for the node pointer to be Null and insert the new node.

```
class clinkedlist:
  def __init__(self):
    self.head = None

  def insertat(self,data):
    new_node = Node(data)

    if self.head is None:
        self.head = new_node
    else:
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node
  def traverse(self):
    printval = self.head
    print(printval.data)
    
    while (True):
        printval = printval.next
        print(printval.data)
        if printval == self.head:
            break


    print(printval)
```